# Serializer field validation with nested serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a model `Manager` that has a ForeignKey to a `User`. 
To update a shipper, I send a `PATCH` method with nested objects like `{"user": {"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "email": "john@doe.com"}`

```
class CompanyManagerMeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserMeSerializer()
    company = CompanyFullSerializer()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user', {})
        user = instance.user
        for key, val in user_data.items():
            setattr(user, key, val)
        user.save()

        company_data = validated_data.pop('company', {})
        company = instance.company
        for key, val in company_data.items():
            setattr(company, key, val)
        company.save()

        for key, val in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, val)
        instance.save()

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyManager
        fields = ("pk", "user", "company", "display_name")
        read_only_fields = ("display_name",)
```

This was all working fine until I added a validator on the `email` field of the `UserMeSerializer`:

```
class UserMeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[UniqueValidator(
            queryset=User.objects.all(),
            message=_("This email address is already used.")
        )]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'pk', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'date_joined', 'last_login'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('pk', 'date_joined', 'last_login')
```

Now the validation will fail because the UserMeSerializer doesn't get the `instance` parameter, so the unique check doesn't know that the email address it finds is the one we're checking... [see the source of UniqueValidator](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/a9a097496ec86d4b5e7db756fe51a39a57f5b370/rest_framework/validators.py#L148-L155)

So my question is: how can I tell the `UserMeSerializer` that I'm working on the `companymanager.user` instance? Should I override `is_valid`?

Answer (score -1):

I believe writing a custom validator extending `UniqueValidator` would help.
You can check the context and set `self.instance` accordingly. For that you have to implement [set_context()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#using-set_context) method.